# Regex: Matching individual characters without matching characters inbetween

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple regex query.

Here is the input:

```
DLWLALDYVASQASV
```

The desired output are the positions of the bolded characters. DLWLAL**DY**VA**S**QASV

So it would be D:6, Y:7, S:10.

I am using python, so I know I can use `span()` or `start()` to obtain the start positions of a match. But if I try to use something like: `DY.{2}S` It will match the characters in between and only give me the position of the first (and last in the case of span) character of the match.

Is there a function or a way to retrieve the position of each specified character, not including the characters in-between?

Comment: What you are try to do is a bit unclear, why you don't want the first D or the last S? D and Y must be together, in this case what the point to extract Y position? (same question for S if you already know that it is two characters after Y)

Comment: Also, note `re.match(r'DY.{2}S', 'DLWLALDYVASQASV')` returns `None` for this. I'm not exactly sure why though.

Comment: I only want the positions of those specified characters because they pertain to specific residues in a protein sequence.

Comment: If you use `[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'DY.{2}S', 'DLWLALDYVASQASV')]`, for example, you'd get `[(6, 11)]`, if that's at all helpful.

Comment: @EliSadoff Thank you, I am aware you can do that, but that only retrieves 2 positions. I need all three.

Comment: @Dider, if you know that the middle 2 are filler, then can't you just get what you want from that? Like if you get `[6, 11]`. You'd know that `DY` is at `str[6:8]` and `S` is at `str[10:11]`.

Comment: @EliSadoff Indeed I can, but I was hoping for a more direct way from the re library. I suppose I'll just have to go with slicing and use the number of dots as the indices. If you wish you can post it as a solution and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: You can put each character you want the position in a capture group and get the capture groups indexes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Could you post it as a solution? I'm not quite sure how to do that (getting the capture group indices that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match = re.search(r'(D)(Y)..(S)', 'DLWLALDYVASQASV')
print([match.group(i) for i in range(4)])
>>> ['DYVAS', 'D', 'Y', 'S']
print([match.span(i) for i in range(4)])
>>> [(6, 11), (6, 7), (7, 8), (10, 11)]
print([match.start(i) for i in range(4)])
>>> [6, 6, 7, 10]
```

You can take subexpressions of regular expression into brackets and then access the corresponding substrings via the match object. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#match-objects) of Match object for more details.